# Transacted sessions or XA sessions are not supported with direct transport

Tags: apache-camel, solace

When I use solace as messaging server, I suffered this exception.

```
MessageListenerContainer  -  Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'XXX.QUE' - trying to recover. Cause: Transacted sessions or XA sessions are not supported with direct transport
```

I use `SESSION_TRANSACTED` to commit transaction manually

Here are some configs.

```
<bean id="solacelay2ConnF" class="com.solacesystems.jms.SolJmsUtility" factory-method="createConnectionFactory">
        <property name="host" value="${solace.jms.url}"></property>
        <property name="username" value="${solace.jms.username}"></property>
        <property name="password" value="${solace.jms.password}"></property>
        <property name="VPN" value="${solace.jms.vpn}"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="solace"
        class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
        <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="solacelay2ConnF" />
        <property name="sessionCacheSize" value="30" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="JMSC" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="solace" />
    </bean>
```

```
<camelContext id="JMS_MCI" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <endpoint id="commonJmsMciInQue" uri="JMSC:queue:XXX.QUE">
            <property key="testConnectionOnStartup" value="true" />
            <property key="disableReplyTo" value="true" />
            <property key="concurrentConsumers" value="10" />
            <property key="acknowledgementModeName" value="SESSION_TRANSACTED" />
        </endpoint>
        <route id="JMS_MCI_LISTENER">
            <from ref="commonJmsMciInQue" />
            <from uri="direct:mciMsg" />
            <process ref="mciMsgListener" />
        </route>
</camelContext>
```

Could anyone help?

Thanks very much !~

Comment: I would look at how to configure this with Solace as its an error it reports to you.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you have "Direct Transport" enabled in the connection factory object called solacelay2ConnF on the Solace PubSub+ message broker side. When the Direct Transport mode is enabled, a client cannot create a transacted Session.